# extjs - How to create listener for child component's custom event

Tags: extjs, event-handling, listener

I am using a panel (say parentPanel) having another child panel (say childPanel). How can i fire a custom event from childPanel that will be caught by parentPanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form.Panel', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    title: 'Simple Form',
    bodyPadding: 5,
    width: 350,

    layout: 'anchor',
    defaults: {
        anchor: '100%'
    },

    defaultType: 'textfield',
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.items = [{
            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
            name: 'first',
            allowBlank: false
        }];
        me.callParent(arguments);
    },

    afterRender: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);
        // in case of a form you can also use the findField() method
        // I used down() because it will work with all sort of containers
        me.down('textfield[name=first]').on('change',me.onFirstnameChange,me);
    },

    onFirstnameChange: function(field) {
        // custom handler
    }
});
```

Doing this just on single instances work the same way expect that you will need to use the `afterrender` event instead of the static [template method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-afterRender).

*Note:
I this doesn't fit your needs you will need to post a more detailed question (with example code) for a more detailed answer.*

Edit:

Adding a custom event to a new component:

```
initComponent: function() {
    // ...
    me.addEvents('customeventname');
    // ... 
}
```

you can now register listeners to this events on instances of this component and fire the event by calling `fireEvent('customeventname', args)` where `args` are the arguments you want to call each listeners with.

Comment: -This looks fine to me. Just the thing is am not using the components predefined event('change' in your example). I want to fire a custom event in textfield. Please update the example with child having fireEvent()

Comment: @VVK Hmm, I am not sure if I got you right... I added some more information to my post. If this still didn't help you, you will need to supply more information. Do you want to fire a custom event for a new component? Fire a event by yourself in name of another component - if so, what is the trigger here?

Comment: -Thanks. BTW can i catch customeventname in Panel without adding listener to textfield(say i have many textfields and i don't want to find and add listener to each field).

Comment: @VVK No you can't. But you can bubble up the events which get then fired by the bubble target. The bubble target could then register to it's own event...